# validate text area box after clicking particular radio button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

hi my code in html is like this

```
 <input type="radio" name='answer_value1[<?php echo $survey1->id?>]' value="<?php echo $answer1->id?>" validate="required:true" id="<?php $answer1->valdt == '1' ? print "welcome":""?>" />
```

And this is code for comment box

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="55" name="nn[<?php echo $survey1->id?>]" id="comment" ></textarea>
```

if the radio button id is "welcome" then i want to make the textarea should be validate otherwise not.

and i wrote some code in jquery

```
   $(function() {
    $('input[id="welcome"]')).change(function() {
    $('textarea[id="comment"]').each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,

        } );        
    } );
```

If i click this field first and after if i clicked another radio button it's still validate this textarea field.
please give me some idea

Comment: @Barmar 
 if($answer1->valdt=="1")
     {
     $validate[$i]="validate='required:true'";
     }

Comment: That's server code, not AJAX. Post the Javascript code you tried. Are you using a validation library? If you use jQuery, there's a good one at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: @bamar I edit the code please view and suggest me .

Comment: Are these elements being created in a PHP loop? You need to ensure that IDs are unique. Using `.each()` with an ID selector makes no sense, since there can only be one matching element. And it's more idiomatic to use `$("#welcome")` than `$("[id=welcome]"). Regarding the validation code, I suggest you look at some of the examples in the documentation, you've got it all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, ajax is not for validation. Its for asynchronous fetching of data from the server.

```
if (document.getElementById('welcome').checked) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('comment');

    if (textarea.value = '') {
        // validation failed
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @UjwalKoirala Edited the code, you can put it in your form submit event. is it what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

var v = document.getElementById("validation1");
ValidatorValidate(v);

by this line of code you can force validator to check validation.
so you can add validation control for your textBox and run above code on radio button selectedChanged event handler.

Comment: @HM19984ir Sir, Can you please describe which code should i put where?